# Proper way to write Part of id as variable in selector id

Tags: jquery

I need the right format to write part of id as a variable.

road1, road2, road3, road4 are control IDs, and the `i` is variable which I am running in a `for` loop. `road` is fixed.

```
$("#road+i+").val("something")
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#road"+i).value("something")`

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
$("#road"+i).value("something");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `i` must be outside the `" "`

```
$("#road"+i).value("something")
```

Comment: what if var was in the middle ? $("#road"+i+"afafd").value("something")

Answer (score 0):

Also, if using jQuery use val()

```
$("#road"+i).val("something")
```